# Cannot call specific method on closing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window where I need to fire a specific method when this window closing, I did:

```
public FooWindow()
{
   Closing += (x, y) => Exit();
}

private void Exit()
{
   if (someVariable)
   {
       Environment.Exit(1);
   }
   else
   {
      Close(); 
   }
```

}

when the Exit event is called the close method is reached but I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don´t see any code that sets the visibility or calls `Show`. Anyway why do you exit the app on closing? Wouldnt this hapen anyway? Or is your form called from another one? In thie latter case you shpuld close the **parent** window, not the program.

Comment: because I use the exit method also in another method, so I cannot close the app in the closing event but I need to call exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are calling `Close();` when the `Closing` event is called. Which sounds to me that you are trying to close a window that is already in the process of closing itself.

That said, if you still want the `Exit()` method to close if your `someVariable` is false. Track the 'closing' status of your form with a boolean, something like the following:

```
private bool _isClosing = false;
public FooWindow()
{
   Closing += (x, y) => {
       _isClosing = true;
       Exit(); 
   };
}

private void Exit()
{
   if (someVariable)
   {
       Environment.Exit(1);
   }
   else
   {
      if (!_isClosing) Close(); 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `Close()` while the window is already closing. So WPF checks for that scenario and launches you the exception to notice the error. Here the call stack I got reproducing your problem. See that the code launching the exception has a self evident name `VerifyNotClosing`:

```
   in System.Windows.Window.VerifyNotClosing()
   in System.Windows.Window.InternalClose(Boolean shutdown, Boolean ignoreCancel)
   in System.Windows.Window.Close()
   in WpfApp1.MainWindow.MainWindow_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) in MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 32
   in System.Windows.Window.OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Window.WmClose()
```

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,9eff3c5633604c43   - source code for WIndow.Close() - just for completeness sake

Answer (score 0):

[Window.Close()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,9eff3c5633604c43) calls [InternalClose()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,25d7e5b48381f32f) which calls [VerifyNotClosing()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,08803a2385930d32) which throws:

> ```
> private void VerifyNotClosing()
> {
>      if (_isClosing == true)
>      {
>           throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidOperationDuringClosing));
>      }
>
>      if (IsSourceWindowNull == false && IsCompositionTargetInvalid == true)
>      {
>           throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidCompositionTarget));
>      }
> }
> ```

`_isClosing` is set to true by `InternalClose()` on your first visit. `SR.Get(SRID.InvalidCompositionTarget)` is the error message you see.